# KOMA-Script numbering enddot

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, punctuation, minitoc

Currently, I'm trying to add a dot after numbers of a section or a subsection with KOMA-Script class. I already found some questions about this subject with the option `enddot` or `endperiod` but it does not work. After some research I found that the problem comes from the package `minitoc`. As soon as I load it the dots disappear and even if I comment the `\usepackage[francais]{minitoc}` dots won't be back.

After commenting the command,I have to delete the "`myfile.aux`" to bring back dots.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,numbers=enddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[francais]{minitoc} % sommaires
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{My section}
\subsection{My subsection}
\end{document}
```

This gives a table of contents with dots after numbers, but in the document the section/subsection title won't have dots.

[image]

I would like my numbers of section/subsection title to be the same as the numbers in the table of contents.

How can I obtain this? Should I remove `minitoc` package?

Comment: minitoc changes `\@sect` and so breaks quite a number of  KOMA-adaptions to section.

Comment: then how can i overcome this ?

Comment: You should not use `minitoc`. You may setup the teble of content yourself with integrated KOMAScript commands. Read the manual chapter 15 for details. In addition, take a look at the different `\addtokomafont`-commands

Comment: There is imho no simple solution -- and it also depends on why you are using minitoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [KOMA-Script from pre-release 3.23.2580](http://www.komascript.de/current) I get

[image: Seems to be OK]

from

```
\documentclass[a4paper,numbers=enddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\dosecttoc
\tableofcontents
\section{My section}
\secttoc
\subsection{My subsection}
\end{document}
```

But also in the `log` file:

```
Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `minitoc' together
(scrartcl)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrartcl)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrartcl)              package `minitoc' on input line 4.
```

and

```
Class scrartcl Warning: Redefining minitoc's internal command `\stc@sect'
(scrartcl)              to prevent minitoc to destroy several features
(scrartcl)              of KOMA-Script on input line 4.
```